# open a new window for a link,but want next page still in the frame "main-body"

Tags: javascript, ajax

[open a new window for a link,but want next page still in the frame "main-body"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jk3Q4.jpg)

In a browser, we used to open a new window for a link which is in a frame, then open next page in same frame, and with other frames like before, just working as facebook.

open a new window for a link,but want next page still in the frame "main-body".

Comment: you need to fix your question (you can do this by clicking the _"edit"_ link). Be more detailed, perhaps add images or examples. Its too confusing the way it is.

Comment: You are looking for Ajax. Try to google for that, learn it an do come back with focused questions

Comment: I change my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook doesn't use frames. It is implemented as a [SPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application) which uses [Ajax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) to pull in new content and [the history API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API) to provide useful things to link to.

If you did want to handle this with frames, then you would need to check (when each page loaded) if `window === top` and, if it did not, redirect (with `top.location = ...`) to a new Frameset document which loaded all the desired documents into its various frames.